# Implemenation of 'may be used' in Use case diagram

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

A case diagram has use case "Manage shopping cart". I need to add "View purchase" which used use case "Manage shopping cart" and add "Delete item" which **may be used by use case** "Manage shopping cart".

My attempt is here: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eajvQ.jpg)

But I am not sure with my implementation of: *"which may be used by use case"* and orientation direction.

Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe this question makes sense to people in your class...

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Wait until the question is closed and you'll see. Btw. Customer, not Costumer.

Comment: I am sorry but when will be question closed? My mistake, rightly is customer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant to say that your question is comprehensible to me. It looks like a school assignment, but without any of the context.

Comment: It is not school assignment or any homework. It is example from school and I do not want to you fill and drawing up but I want only check my result, where is under the link. I am sorry, but I dont know what do you mean "without any of the context" ? I wrote task and my result and I beg control.

Comment: Now the question looks understandable and deserves +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, the sentence should be: "which may be used BY use case...". I have edited the question. That can be realized by `extend` arrow, as you have drawn it.

As for your diagram, it lacks arrows from customer to `view content` and to `delete item`. The customer can use these operations, can't he?

Comment: I think not because it's accessible via the manage shopping cart. Thank you for editing

Comment: way of acces doesn't matter. A different functionality is not connected with using it Actor only if he uses a functionality that uses that additional one. You haven't that here.